# Metaclass delete domain method in Grails 2 unit test

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I am trying to test the throwing of an exception in my unit test.  I tried to metaclass the delete method, but it doesn't want to stick.  Can you tell from the code what I'm doing wrong?

Unit Test code:

```
@TestFor(ProductController)
@TestMixin(DomainClassUnitTestMixin)
class ProductControllerTests {     
  void testDeleteWithException() {
    mockDomain(Product, [[id: 1, name: "Test Product"]])
    Product.metaClass.delete = {-> throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("I'm an       exception")}
    controller.delete(1)
    assertEquals(view, '/show/edit')
}
```

Controller action code:

```
def delete(Long id) {
    def productInstance = Product.get(id)
    if (!productInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'product.label', default: 'Product'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
        return
    }

    try {
        productInstance.delete(flush: true)
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'product.label', default: 'Product'), id])
        redirect(action: "list")
    }
    catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.deleted.message', args: [message(code: 'product.label', default: 'Product'), id])
        redirect(action: "show", id: id)
    }
}
```

When I run the test, `productInstance.delete(flush: true)` does not throw the exception I'm expecting. Instead it redirects to `action: "list"`. Does anyone know how to override the Product.delete() method so I can force the exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're mocking `delete` without any arguments, but your controller calls `delete(flush: true)`.  Try mocking out `delete(Map)` like this:

```
Product.metaClass.delete = { Map params -> 
    throw new DataIntegrityViolationException("...")
}
```

Comment: You're absolutely right.  I had used an attrs before like so `delete = {attrs -> ... }`, but I hadn't thought to use a specific type like Map.  Thank you, this was really starting to bug me.